# R forking and environments/pointers

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fork, clone, environment

While using parallelization R seems to copy everything that is returned from a child process, even when the objects are not changed. In particular, consider the following example:

```
env1 <- new.env()
envs2 <- lapply(1:4, function(x) env1)

cl<-makeCluster(2, type="FORK")
envs3 <- parLapply(cl, 1:4, function(x) env1)
envs4 <- parLapply(cl, 1:4, function(x) capture.output(str(env1)))
stopCluster(cl)

env1
envs2
envs3
envs4
```

First I make an environment (`env1`). Then using the non-parallel `lapply` I get a list (`envs2`) where all entries contain a pointer to `env1`. Now when using the parallel `parLapply` the entries in the list I get (`envs3`) contain pointers to different object, which are supposedly clones of `env1` (Also note that the first two entries contain the same pointer as the last two; supposedly because I use 2 child nodes for a loop of length 4). This cloning seems to happen when the child node returns their results to the master. To see this I save the pointer of `env1` in the child nodes to the list `envs4`.

Why are untouched environments cloned at the moment they are returned?, and is there a way to make R not clone environments that are not changed?